# C# Logic Conflict within a condition

Tags: c#

Relevant misc info:
Project = Tic Tac Toe (console app)

My issue is the following:
I have an array that initially is filled with 0's which MUST stay as 0's unless the user takes a move (then it'll become a 1) or the computer makes a move then it becomes a 2.
Example code:

```
else if (posStatus[2] != 0 && posStatus[5] != 0 && posStatus[8] != 0 && (posStatus[2] + posStatus[5] + posStatus[8] % 2 == 0))
{
    if (posStatus[2] == 0)
    {
        posStatus[2] = 2;
        return;
    }
    else if (posStatus[5] == 0)
    {
        posStatus[5] = 2;
        return;
    }
    else if (posStatus[8] == 0)
    {
        posStatus[8] = 2;
        return;
    }
```

issue:
There is a grid that is 9 long which three rows, 3 columns and two diagonals. Initially all values are set to 0 and this is used to determine if the space is free so changing to another type would cause issues. If the value 1 is held player 1 has played there. If the value 2 is held the computer has played there.

So originally I had put in

```
posStatus[0] + posStatus[1] + posStatus[2] % 2 == 0)
```

Which decides where the computer will play in this case it will be the first row if the enemy player has put 2 values there which logically should work perfectly and it does apart from my issue which is as follows:

When nothing is played on a row the values are: 0, 0 ,0 if you do 0 + 0 + 0 % 2 you'll discover that equals 0 which is the parameter for the above condition. This means it will attempt to make sure there is a value in each row/column/diagonal which of course is not good as it means the player can win in 3 turns..

So to combat this I added in (I'm aware I can refactor it) I added:

```
posStatus[0] != 0 && posStatus[1] != 0 && posStatus[2] != 0
```

Which means if a row/column/diagonal is empty do not play there which means it never plays in empty rows/columns/diagonals which is an issue.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check few conditions for each time, need not to consider the sequence. Possible cases of win for any player would be:
0,1,2

0,3,6

0,4,8

1,4,7

2,4,6

2,5,8

3,4,5

AND 6,7,8

I am assuming that numbering is row wise and started from 0.

Now you have to tell computer based on the input of user.

For example:

User has selected 2, so you have `posStatus[2] = 1` Now the only cells you have to check are  0,1,4,5 and 6 as these are the only possible cells for win.

To handle the beginning of game situation, you have two options:

1. Let the user start always.
2. Start anyone from 0,2,6 and 8 as these are part of the maximum solutions.

**Another Approach:**

There are 3 possibilities of success:

A. Row wise : Add or substitute number by 1 and check status ,

B. Column wise : Add or substitute number by 3 and check status ,

C. Diagonally : Add or substitute number by 2 AND 4 then check status

For example if user has selected `i` cell. Your check should be:

A. See the status of `(i-2),(i-1),(i+1) AND (i+2)` - Obviously this should be in range of 0-8

B. See the status of `(i-6),(i-3),(i+3) AND (i+6)`

C. See the status of `(i-8),(i-4),(i-2),(i+2),(i+4) AND (i+8)`

Comment: You are correct, the numbering starts from 0. I can make this into a 2D array if need be. I'm sorry, I'm not following your suggestion. I  already have that all done. My problem is with how the computer calculates where to play. I found min max to confusing to do myself so I decided to it mathmatically. The user always starts and currently the computers actions are always based of the users unless no good move is possible then it'll do a random possible move.

Comment: I have added another approach, see if this can help you

Comment: Reading it now, friendly bump while I try to figure it out since your the only one providing help.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to redo how it does this but I have no clue how to :(